# accessing usb drive for storage after making it bootable with 16.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, usb

I used both etcher and startup disk creator to make a live USB to install Ubuntu 16.04 from iso file. I used a sandisk 16gb drive.

I was able to install 16.04 all right. The problem is that the USB stick is now unusable for anything else. It shows only about 1.5gb of storage split into sdb1 and sdb2. Windows formatting does not work. the stick still has the same files and the same amount of storage.

gparted cannot delete the two partitions. The only way recover the disk seems to wipe it with

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: Have you try creating a new partition table using Gparted or writing anything to sdb1 or sdb2?

Comment: Why Gparted cannot delete the partitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you don't want to wait the whole time..
type dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sbd for some seconds
wait until it corrupts current filesystem. (only a few seconds)
On gparted, it will state you have a corrupt MBR or GPT (up to you)
Go to Gparted -> Devices -> Create a Table of Records
choose beetween MBR or GPT.
After that, create a new partition.
There are probably smarter ways, but this one is pretty fast.

Comment: As far as I know, you don't have to corrupt the partition table just to create a new one. Gparted can do that regardless of whether the current partition table is corrupted or not.

Comment: that's ok. but I don't know why, on my experience, the pendrive with ubuntu keeped mounting, and that may have confused gparted. I don't know why... just happened with me.

Comment: If the pendrive keeps remounting itself after you have manually unmounted it, I guess there is another problem with your system. You should ask another question for this problem if that is the case.

Comment: long time i did this, perhaps its not even this way anymore. I red it was something related to automount feature and iso9669 filesystems mounting. I don't know perhaps the way the pendrive is pre-mounted with iso9669 is different from usual. it is mounted as readonly, this could affect gparted when it tries to write the MBR. I don't know.